# In emacs, how do I force certain characters to act as end of statement delineators?

Tags: emacs, syntax, grammar

I've created a new major mode derived from cc-mode, because I'm using a meta-language that is mostly C-like, but is parsed to generate code automatically.

Say I have something like this:

```
struct MyNewStruct
{
    int newInt = 32;
    {
        [flag, different-flag]
        string newString = "foo";
    }
}
```

I need the ']' character to effectively be equivalent to the ; or the next line, declaring the string, doesn't indent properly.

I've tried using M-x modify-syntax-entry for ']' and making it both a closing character as well as a punctuation character (according to the GNU manual on syntax tables), but it doesn't look like it's allowed to belong to two character classes simultaneously (unless one of those character classes is a comment). (And if it's just a punctuation character, that causes other problems.)

I can't change the grammar of the meta-language, so adding a semicolon after the close bracket isn't possible.

Comment: Syntax categories aren't what matters here. Leave the `]` as a closing character. You need to fiddle with the CC mode indentation rules; the [indentation engine chapter in the manual](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Indentation-Engine-Basics.html) is where I suggest you start.

Comment: I took a look at the indentation categories previously, but I honestly feel like they're not really fixing the right problem. If I analyse the line after the brackets, I get statement-cont as the context. That's wrong. Fixing the indentation of statement-cont will BREAK statement-cont for all other situations, like if I have a line that's too long and needs to carry on.

Comment: Try something like labels, perhaps. The indentation categories are what controls indentation, not the character categories.

Comment: I suppose the real issue is the syntactic analysis and not the actual character category; I have to modify the analysis so that a statement-cont that ends in a ']' is actually a statement. I don't see any way to do this without copying and pasting and modifying the cc-mode function(s) that control the indentation rules. I was hoping to avoid that, but I guess there's nothing for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the real answer was to pick something that was syntactically closer to my meta-language. csharp-mode already parses the brackets correctly and marks sections enclosed in brackets as statements, not statement-cont.